# What's a good iPhone running app with a heart rate monitor?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a combination of an app like [RunKeeper](http://RunKeeper.com) that tracks my running speed, with an app (+hardware?) to track my heart rate.

I'm currently running with RunKeeper (to track my speed) and also wearing an chestband+wristwatch (to track my heart rate). It would be nice to get rid of the wristwatch, if there's some app (and chestband receiver hardware?) to combine the data.

I've seen [some apps](http://www.iphoneness.com/iphone-apps/best-heart-rate-monitors-for-iphone/) that only do heart rate monitoring, but I don't want to switch between 2 apps while running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Runtastic](http://runtastic.com) has a solution for heart-rate sensor bands communicating with the Runtastic apps (which are similar to RunKeeper) via a sensor key which is attached to the iPhone: http://runtastic.com/en/sensors

The dongle is as expensive as for the Digifit, but the app is a lot more affordable.

Comment: Excellent - this is what I was looking for. Agree, it's not cheap, but as long as it's standards-based, it can be used with other software as well. Does the Nike stuff use this standard, or their own?

Answer (score 3):

There is [Digifit](http://digifit.me/irunner/) which is software that works with any ANT+ enabled devices by brand names such as Adidas, Garmin, StarTrac and Timex.

Comment: This looks interesting, it's the closest match so far to what I asked for. It just seems a bit expensive, as iPhone apps go: $30 for the app plus $80-100 for the receiver dongle. Still, good answer!

Answer (score 2):

#### Wahoo Fitness

You might like to check out [Wahoo Fitness](http://wahoofitness.com) - it's also an Ant+ dongle like Digifit, but unlike Digifit it works with a whole different ecosystem of apps (not just the default Digifit one) - defintely the widest range of all the apps you've listed here, and including Runkeeper as well so you don't need to change which running app you use.

[image: heart reate monitor]

[image: can use this with lots of different apps]

Good luck, and happy running.

Answer (score 1):

My friend, there is no need stop using Runkeeper!
Runkeeper is fully compatible with great chest heart rate monitor - [Beets BLU HRM](http://beetsblu.com/sensor/)! 
I use it with Runkeeper every day and I'm really satisfied.

There are also detailed setup insructions for Runkeeper on their  website: http://beetsblu.com/apps/app-store/runkeeper/

Answer (score 0):

I use [**Nike+**](http://www.apple.com/ipod/nike/) (iPod Nano and iPhone 3Gs+) to run and measure all my distances, they even have a [**website that you can control your running**](http://nikerunning.nike.com/nikeos/p/nikeplus/en_US/plus/#//dashboard/?sitesrc=uslp), join runners, do running contests, etc ...

I'm very pleased with the entire solution.

And they have a **Polar Heart Rate accessory** now that will also monitored your heart beat.

though Nike+ App needs a little update, I love it!

P.S. I do not have a Nike+ Shoes... I use Asics, and I just put the sensor above my foot, works great!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Only works for iPod nano (5th gen and newer). Not iPhone.

Comment: Nike+ works with iPhone 4.

Comment: Nike+ works on iPhone 3GS !

Comment: Nike+ works but doesn't support heart rate monitor!

Comment: @torbengb There is no iPod Touch 5th gen, the latest is 4th. Secondly Nike team up with Polar and all works. http://gizmodo.com/5558235/heart-rate-monitor-for-nike%252B-to-track-your-ticker

Comment: @balexandre, I'm specifically looking for something that works with the iPhone. According to the page you referred to, this only "Works with Nike+ SportBand and 5th generation iPod nano" -- not iPhone, and not iPod Touch -- only nano. Can you point me to a page that specifically states that this thing works on iPhone 4?

Answer (score 0):

I use Cyclemeter and Digifit at the same time Cyclemeter gives me updates thru my ear piece and I have Digifit running Visual

Answer (score 0):

Polar app for iPhone keeps tabs on your heart:

> Polar USA, longtime experts in fit tech, recently introduced a free iPhone training app that works with the company’s $80 Polar H7 Heart Rate Sensor. This product focuses more on gathering workout info, including where you went (if you run or jog), and how long you worked out.

This was copied and pasted from
http://www.pcworld.com/article/2024238/bluetooth-powers-gizmos-for-health-wristwatches-and-more.html

Answer (score 0):

I use the [iSmoothRun](http://www.ismoothrun.com/) app on my iPhone 4S with a [Wahoo BlueHR HRM](http://www.wahoofitness.com/Products/Wahoo-Fitness-Wahoo-Blue-HR-Heart-Rate-Strap.asp). This is an *excellent* combo because:

- iSmoothRun is independent. It can export your data to many different sites including Nike+ and Runkeeper (and dropbox!)
- iSmoothRun has very customizable exercise and voice feedback settings
- iSmoothRun listens to its users' feedback and fixes issues quickly
- The HRM is Bluetooth so it does not require a dongle (less bulk!)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the new Polar Bluetooth heart rate monitor with my iPhone 5 and Runkeeper and it works fine.

You can see three graphs on your webpage for free: pace, altitude and heart rate. I posted at Nike support and the answer is that they are thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting example of how the software got ahead of the hardware on iOS where the initial year or two of sensors were proprietary and locked to one vendor.

Today, you have several options for sensors that use Bluetooth 4.0 LE and can send heart rate signals to just about any app you choose.

I would look for a monitor that isn't tied to one app:

- [Wahoo Blue HRM](http://www.wahoofitness.com/wahoo-blue-hr-heart-rate-strap.html) - chest mounted with elastic straps
- [Mio Alpha](http://www.mioglobal.com/) - wrist watch (fairly large one at that)
- [Mio Link](http://www.mioglobal.com/en-us/mio-link-heart-rate-band.htm) - wrist band that just collects rate data and is much smaller than the Alpha.

Most of the apps that are focused on fitness and running will seamlessly integrate the heart rate data into your workout tracking.

Answer (score 0):

A great iPhone running app with a built-in heart rate monitor is the Nike Run Club app. It offers comprehensive tracking of your running speed and distance, and it can also connect to compatible heart rate monitors, eliminating the need for a separate wristwatch. If you're interested in learning [how to make an app like Runkeeper](https://www.cleveroad.com/blog/smart-fitness--how-to-build-a-runkeeper-app-and-become-the-market-leader/), there are various online resources and tutorials available that provide step-by-step guidance on app development for fitness tracking purposes.

Comment: Thanks for contributing!  One quick question/clarification:  This goes from recommending an app to a resource to creating an app - I'm not seeing the connection here.  Can you clarify?